# How to pass onClick funtion into a span created using string literals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an HTML object created using string literals and used  Dangerously Set HTML. Basically, I just had to create span and pass onClick while creating the string literal but when I pass the function which is bound in the constructor. later I get the error that this is not a function. How can I pass a function in onClick while creating the HTML object using string literals in react?
this HTML is set dangerously in render().

```
var html=`<span onClick="myFunc()">${text}</span>`;
```

Comment: Why do you need to construct it with a string literal as opposed to jsx?

Comment: is there a reason why you can't do `var html = <span onClick={this.myFunc}>{text}</span>`?

Comment: There is some DOM manipulation I need to do to create some text inside a span with click function.

Comment: use jquery on listener

Comment: is it wise to use react and jquery in the same react component?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? maybe we might help you. Instead of doing that, you can create a span component `<Span text={'some text'} onClick={myFunc} />` and pass your data to it.

Comment: "is it wise to use react and jquery in the same react component?"  Generally speaking, no.

Comment: @JuniusL. I am converting the HTML into the string  and set it dangerously in the render.so when I pass onClick later it does not trigger the onClick event

Answer (score 0):

this just a string, you can't have eventListerner on it.

Or declare a DOM element like this

```
var MySpan = Document​.create​Element('span');
MySpan.textContent = text;
MySpan.onclick = myFunc;


//....

function myFunc() {
  alert('span clicked !');
}
```

Comment: when I just pass alert in onClick in the string literal it shows alert but the function I passed shows an error .

Comment: Maybe using createElement like yours above code will solve the problem. haven't tried yet. but ain't using string literals also the same thing?

Comment: You're a weird type: you do not try my code, and you tell me it's generating an error that I'm supposed to guess with a crystal ball ...

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this: var html = {text}.
Now the 'html' can be sue as pure component in he mail component to render in DOM but here this.myFunc is wrong because pure component will not carry any scope by itself , ou have to pass the function as prop or use HOC for that.

And for more clearity kindly gothrough this pure component documentation of react :[react pure component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html)

Comment: the main problem is I am manipulating the HTML as the string for giving a class to certain text by creating the span for the certain text with click event for it but I am not able to do it